# How to make Mathematica use system GTK style under Linux?

Tags: front-end, installation

Under Linux, *Mathematica* uses preinstalled QT themes, but I'm sure that it's possible to make it use system GTK style. How?

Comment: Just don't do it.  Mathematica works fine regardless of what it looks like.  This has been asked before and it used to be possible by removing the Qt libraries that ship with Mathematica and replacing them with symlinks to your system's Qt (of the same major version), if I remember right.  But doing this can cause problems.  So don't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution found! Install `qt4-qtconfig`. Launch it, select GTK+ in the *Select GUI Style* dropdown menu, and then save your updated configuration from the File menu in the menubar.

Comment: Note that in some systems, the package is `qtconfig-qt4`.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández Did this work without having to replace the Qt libraries that Mathematica ships with?

Comment: @Szabolcs well, not really; it doesn't use native GTK+, but at least it uses your theme colours, which is a bit nicer than the boring brown/grey and does indeed feel more native. Here a comparison: http://cl.ly/image/0g0m2N0G062d

Answer (score 5):

Preferences -> Advanced -> Open Options Inspector.

In the Options Inspector window:

Global Options -> PrivateFrontEndOptions

In the right pane: "XDefaultApplicationStyle": by default, it is "plastique". Change it to "windows", for example, or other styles defined in qt4-qtconfig. You can also change the font "Bitstream Vera Sans-10" to "Bitstream Vera Sans-8", for example, to reduce the font size a little.

Comment: Nice. Managed to change the font, however setting `XDefaultApplicationStyle` to `GTK+` (how it is displayed on qt4-qtconfig) or `gtk+` doesn't seem to have any effect.