# Mathematica's GUI menus look bad on Linux

Tags: front-end, linux, menu

I installed Mathemaica on Arch Linux several days ago.  Everything is well, except for the fact that menus in the GUI look real bad.  I have things set up in a way that Qt apps (such as Mathematica) should mimic GTK styles as closely as possible.

However, Mathematica's GUI menu looks rather crappy (side-by-side comparison with a nicely-looking Qt app):
[image: Mathematica GUI menus]

Has anyone who runs Mathematica on Linux experienced this issue?  Any solutions?

**N.B.** Also posted [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1572901).

Comment: I don't know the present situation, but in the past Mathematica shipped with its private Qt libraries.  Replacing those with the system Qt would allow Mathematica to pick up the system style.  It would also break Mathematica sometimes, which means that it wasn't a good idea to do it *just for the looks*.  I don't know the present situation.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Do you know of any configuration files read by those Qt libraries?

Comment: I don't see any menus in your screen capture. I just see two tabbed dialog windows. Where are the menus that bother you?

Comment: @d125q Sorry, I don't.  If I remember correctly, when I tried this, I simply renamed the Qt libraries that shipped with Mma and put symlinks to the system Qt libraries.  You might try this, but try to use the same version if you can (don't mix Qt 4 and 5 as they're not compatible).

Comment: @m_goldberg: Those tabbed windows are what I refer to as menus.

Comment: Yours looks very nice to me... at least compared to [mine](http://i.imgur.com/c6ptSJ7.png?1).

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95889/36089) helped me solve my problem. If what you don't like is just the slightly darker background, you can change the window colour in `qtconfig-qt4` and the change will be reflect in Mathematica (once you restart it).